# GoogleAuth error in flutter - platformException(network_error, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: , null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want to use Google authentication in flutter.After setting up everything, I encounter  platformException(network_error, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: , null, null) in my code.

I'm running my app in debug mode.

-> I'm connected to a network and internet doesn't seem to be an issue

->I've provided internet permission in Mainifest

->I've added SHA1 and SHA256 keys in firebase settings.(got them using below command in linux)

(

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

)

->I've added google-services.json to my project and setup firebase settings.

->date and time are correct on my device

Checked many previous StackOverflow response, but most responses are for PlatformException(sign_in_failed...,API exception : 10) or other reasons, but not for PlatformException(network_error...,API exception : 7) . examples of solutions tried:

I don't know what is the problem.

Here's my code

class GoogleSignInProvider {
static final googleSignIn=GoogleSignIn();

```
static GoogleSignInAccount? user;

static Future googleLogin() async{
    try{
        
        final googleUser=await googleSignIn.signIn(); //Exception is thrown on this line 
    
        if(googleUser==null) return;
        
        user=googleUser;
        
        final googleAuth=await googleUser.authentication;
        
        final credential=GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
            idToken: googleAuth.idToken
        );
        

        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
        
    }
    on Exception catch(e){
        print(e);
    }
    
}
```

}

Here's the output

[ +859 ms] W/ActivityThread( 8504): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@de192c7
[+4403 ms] I/DecorCaptionView( 8504): Choosing forced status bar color.
[  +72 ms] I/DecorCaptionView( 8504): Choosing forced status bar color.
[        ] I/flutter ( 8504): PlatformException(network_error, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: ,
null, null)